# Setting equal row height in tabularray

Tags: tables, tabularray

I'm making some exercise cards for my students in tabularray, with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0cm, right=0cm, bottom=1cm, top=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
hlines={2pt},
vlines={2pt},
vspan=even,
rowsep=0pt,
colsep=0pt,
column{1}={1.5cm,c,m},
column{2,3}={8.5cm,c,m}
}
1 &
\begin{align*} x+y&=25 \\[1ex] 2x&=14 \end{align*} &
\begin{align*} 2(x+y)&=32 \\[1ex] x-y&=0 \end{align*} \\
2 & 
\begin{align*} 3x-y&=1 \\[1ex] 5x+2y&=9 \end{align*} & 
\begin{align*} 7x-5y&=10 \\[1ex] 2x-3y&=-5 \end{align*} \\
3 &
\begin{gather*} 4(x-2)+3(y-1)=5 \\[1ex] -2(x+5)-7=8y \end{gather*} &
\begin{align*} 4(2x-7)-5y&=0 \\[1ex] 3(3y-4)-4x&=0 \end{align*} \\
4 &
\begin{align*} \frac{x+3}{2}+\frac{y-1}{3}&=6 \\[1ex] \frac{x-1}{2}+\frac{y+3}{5}&=4 \end{align*} &
\begin{gather*} \frac{8x-4}{3}-\frac{4y-2}{2}=-7 \\[1ex] 2-\frac{x+2}{2}=\frac{2y-1}{2} \end{gather*} \\
5 &
Problema & 
En una granja, entre cerdos y gallinas, hay 12 cabezas y 34 patas. ¿Cuántos cerdos y gallinas hay?
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

It's important that all the cards (rows of the table) are the same height, but despite setting vspan=even, the result is like this:

[image]

I would want all the rows to be automatically set to the height of the largest row, namely row 4. Now, I can set the height of the rows manually, with something like rows={3cm}. However, this setting seems to not have any effect unless I set it high enough that none of the rows would get any bad boxes (i.e. if I set rows={1pt} I definitely don't get rows of 1pt of height). This means I have to guess a height large enough for the biggest row, but still as small as possible, so that the rest of the rows can be set at that height. This is a very tedious process and has to be redone every time I change the contents of the cards. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Off-topic: `left=0cm, right=0cm, bottom=1cm, top=1cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `hmargin=0cm, vmargin=1cm`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rows` command of `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0cm, right=0cm, bottom=1cm, top=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
hlines={2pt},
vlines={2pt},
vspan=even,
rowsep=0pt,
colsep=0pt,
column{1}={1.5cm,c,m},
column{2,3}={8.5cm,c,m},
rows={4cm}, % modified this value how you likes
}
1 &
\begin{align*} x+y&=25 \\[1ex] 2x&=14 \end{align*} &
\begin{align*} 2(x+y)&=32 \\[1ex] x-y&=0 \end{align*} \\
2 & 
\begin{align*} 3x-y&=1 \\[1ex] 5x+2y&=9 \end{align*} & 
\begin{align*} 7x-5y&=10 \\[1ex] 2x-3y&=-5 \end{align*} \\
3 &
\begin{gather*} 4(x-2)+3(y-1)=5 \\[1ex] -2(x+5)-7=8y \end{gather*} &
\begin{align*} 4(2x-7)-5y&=0 \\[1ex] 3(3y-4)-4x&=0 \end{align*} \\
4 &
\begin{align*} \frac{x+3}{2}+\frac{y-1}{3}&=6 \\[1ex] \frac{x-1}{2}+\frac{y+3}{5}&=4 \end{align*} &
\begin{gather*} \frac{8x-4}{3}-\frac{4y-2}{2}=-7 \\[1ex] 2-\frac{x+2}{2}=\frac{2y-1}{2} \end{gather*} \\
5 &
Problema & 
En una granja, entre cerdos y gallinas, hay 12 cabezas y 34 patas. ¿Cuántos cerdos y gallinas hay?
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]